# How to print tree in lisp without dolist, only recursion?

Tags: recursion, printing, tree, lisp, common-lisp

INPUT:  (A (B (D (E) (F))) (C) (K))
I currently have two functions, which give me an OUTPUT of:

A

B

C

K

B

D

D

E

F

E

NIL

However I need outputs like this:
a: b c k
b: d
c:
k:
d: e f

e:

f:

or

a

b s k

d

e f

```
(defun print-children (s)
   (cond ((null (caar (cdr s))) nil) 
         (t (print (caar (cdr s))) (print-children (cdr s)))))

(defun print-tree (s)
  (cond ((null s) nil)
        ((atom (car s)) (print (car s)) (print-children s) (print-tree (cdr s)))
        (t (print-tree (car s)))))
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. 'all from the new line' - what does this mean? Your question lacks a useful example of the expected input and output.

Comment: @RainerJoswig changed it, is that clearer?

Comment: @RainerJoswig new to stack, forgot to add all the information

Comment: and what are these functions supposed to do? I can read the code, but for example I have no idea what you intend to do with PRINT-LEVEL.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Print-level (I renamed it print-children) prints immediate children nodes of the main node. The whole questions is in printing a tree BREADTH FIRST.

Comment: Why would you print C and K, but not E and F?

Answer (score 5):

**Node**

The first thing you should define: some data structure functions for the node.

- `nodep` *thing*  -> is thing a node?
- `node-name` *node* -> return the name of the node
- `node-children`*node* -> return the children of the node

**Breadth first**

Then I would define a function to traverse a tree in breadth-first order.

- `breadth-first` *tree* *fn* `&optional` *queue*

This function would call `FN` on all elements of the tree in breadth-first order.

1. if there are no nodes, end
2. take the first node off the queue as current node
3. push the node children of the current node to the end of the queue
4. call the function `FN` on the current node
5. call itself with the *tree* *fn* *queue*

Write this loop above as a recursive function.

**Call BREADTH-FIRST**

```
CL-USER 76 > (breadth-first '(A (B (D (E)
                                      (F)))
                                (C)
                                (K))
                            (lambda (node)
                              (princ (node-name node))
                              (princ ":")
                              (mapc (lambda (child)
                                      (princ (node-name child)))
                                    (node-children node))
                              (terpri)))
A:BCK
B:D
C:
K:
D:EF
E:
F:
```

Comment: how would it look without lambdas?

Comment: our task is restricted to basic functions: car, cdr, cons, cond, for, print, list-length, format, apply, atom, setq